# Normalize and control for missing data in an extreme dataset

Tags: r, transformation, normalization, missing-data

I have the following dataset

```
structure(list(q1 = c(5, 40, 200, 100, 100, 3, 200, 10, 10, 50, 
50, 20, 600, 20, 15, 20, 80, 50, 0, 0, 45, 40, 20, 100, 20, 100, 
3, 30, 10, 3, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 5, 5, 
5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 10, 5, 0, 50), q2 = c(5, 40, 
200, 80, 100, 2, 100, 11, 10, 5, 50, 60, 600, 10, 10, 30, 50, 
0, 0, 0, 45, 30, 10, 20, 20, 20, 5, 30, 30, 3, 20, 0, 20, 0, 
0, 0, 20, 0, 5, 2, 60, 0, 40, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 10, 20, 0, 0), q3 = c(2, 70, 400, 160, 350, 100, 500, 
20, 100, 500, 300, 20, 1000, 20, 20, 200, 80, 100, 70, 50, 0, 
20, 40, 0, 0, 200, 5, 0, 100, 3, 50, 60, 0, 0, 0, 20, 100, 30, 
40, 50, 50, 1000, 60, 0, 10, 160, 20, 40, 40, 200, 20, 20, 15, 
150, 10, 15, 10, 100, 0, 10), q4 = c(50, 30, 300, 160, 300, 100, 
500, 20, 100, 25, 200, 30, 600, 20, 0, 0, 50, 20, 200, 50, 50, 
20, 30, 0, 0, 50, 3, 20, 60, 3, 0, 60, 0, 0, 0, 15, 100, 30, 
30, 20, 100, 1000, 30, 10, 10, 50, 3, 20, 0, 100, 15, 20, 1510, 
0, 10, 20, 0, 50, 0, 0), q5 = c(20, 50, 200, 40, 100, 100, 100, 
15, 20, 50, 50, 50, 1000, 20, 15, 30, 50, 30, 15, 15, 25, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 150, 3, 50, 30, 10, 30, 30, 50, 20, 20, 15, 20, 30, 
8, 20, 100, 500, 30, 10, 30, 20, 3, 20, 20, 15, 30, 0, 45, 20, 
0, 15, 30, 40, 20, 15), q6 = c(0, 70, 100, 160, 100, 100, 50, 
15, 10, 25, 1000, 50, 1000, 20, 0, 0, 80, 0, 0, 0, 35, 30, 10, 
20, 20, 100, 3, 10, 60, 10, 0, 100, 30, 50, 100, 15, 30, 30, 
17, 5, 30, 1000, 80, 20, 30, 80, 40, 80, 20, 20, 40, 30, 30, 
0, 0, 20, 10, 40, 20, 50), q7 = c(5, 50, 200, 100, 100, 5, 20, 
10, 0, 300, 50, 20, 300, 20, 0, 200, 80, 10, 15, 0, 30, 20, 40, 
20, 20, 100, 3, 15, 50, 15, 80, 20, 0, 30, 0, 15, 20, 30, 10, 
20, 30, 100, 70, 20, 3, 20, 30, 40, 30, 10, 15, 0, 30, 30, 0, 
5, 50, 30, 0, 30), q8 = c(0, 30, 50, 100, 20, 5, 5, 8, 10, 5, 
30, 20, 100, 20, 0, 0, 50, 20, 0, 0, 35, 20, 20, 0, 30, 20, 5, 
6, 30, 15, 10, 10, 30, 0, 0, 0, 20, 30, 6, 5, 50, 100, 10, 10, 
5, 35, 20, 80, 20, 20, 15, 0, 15, 0, 0, 5, 10, 40, 0, 15), q9 = c(20, 
40, 0, 180, 0, 0, 0, 1, 20, 500, 100, 20, 1000, 0, 20, 0, 80, 
50, 0, 15, 45, 20, 20, 0, 20, 200, 3, 80, 50, 15, 30, 30, 30, 
0, 20, 0, 50, 0, 45, 200, 0, 0, 5, 20, 10, 180, 50, 90, 20, 50, 
20, 0, 15, 0, 0, 30, 50, 40, 0, 30), q10 = c(10, 70, 0, 200, 
0, 0, 10, 1, 15, 15, 100, 20, 1000, 0, 0, 0, 80, 30, 0, 10, 30, 
30, 10, 0, 15, 20, 5, 30, 40, 15, 10, 30, 100, 0, 0, 5, 50, 30, 
20, 15, 30, 0, 5, 10, 10, 90, 25, 90, 15, 25, 20, 0, 15, 0, 0, 
35, 10, 20, 0, 15), q11 = c(20, 60, 200, 120, 100, 9, 100, 15, 
25, 150, 100, 30, 100, 20, 15, 50, 80, 50, 20, 15, 30, 20, 30, 
20, 15, 150, 10, 20, 50, 10, 35, 20, 50, 20, 0, 20, 0, 30, 35, 
20, 80, 100, 60, 20, 50, 20, 60, 20, 50, 25, 35, 0, 30, 0, 0, 
30, 30, 40, 20, 20), q12 = c(20, 50, 200, 120, 100, 3, 50, 12, 
10, 15, 50, 30, 100, 20, 0, 30, 60, 0, 0, 5, 25, 30, 10, 20, 
10, 1000, 5, 0, 60, 10, 20, 0, 5, 25, 0, 15, 0, 30, 31, 2, 35, 
1000, 10, 10, 15, 20, 25, 80, 50, 20, 35, 0, 20, 0, 0, 10, 20, 
30, 0, 15), q13 = c(200, 80, 0, 200, 25, 200, 10, 20, 50, 15, 
1000, 70, 1000, 50, 0, 0, 80, 40, 30, 0, 100, 30, 20, 20, 40, 
100, 5, 50, 100, 20, 0, 30, 30, 0, 50, 10, 30, 30, 45, 10, 120, 
1000, 50, 202, 100, 200, 15, 120, 25, 20, 35, 0, 45, 0, 50, 50, 
50, 30, 0, 30), q14 = c(0, 50, 200, 200, 0, 5, 100, 5, 20, 300, 
300, 40, 1000, 10020, 20, 0, 80, 30, 0, 15, 50, 50, 20, 0, 40, 
300, 3, 20, 100, 5, 0, 50, 100, 0, 0, 0, 30, 100, 20, 100, 40, 
100, 5, 10, 10, 10, 50, 120, 0, 50, 15, 50, 50, 0, 50, 15, 100, 
40, 0, 50), q15 = c(50, 40, 50, 150, 100, 30, 0, 8, 25, 100, 
100, 100, 0, 100, 0, 0, 50, 10, 0, 50, 150, 1000, 10, 0, 120, 
0, 5, 100, 20, 10, 10, 0, 100, 0, 0, 5, 100, 30, 45, 200, 100, 
200, 20, 5, 0, 0, 50, 100, 50, 100, 10, 0, 0, 0, 50, 30, 100, 
50, 0, 50), q16 = c(50, 50, 200, 100, 200, 15, 200, 15, 50, 500, 
150, 50, 1000, 20, 0, 100, 100, 30, 0, 50, 60, 30, 50, 100, 100, 
100, 10, 100, 100, 15, 200, 50, 30, 0, 0, 15, 30, 30, 5, 50, 
15, 1000, 5, 20, 100, 0, 80, 20, 0, 300, 20, 0, 100, 0, 0, 20, 
100, 100, 0, 200), q17 = c(0, 30, 100, 140, 100, 5, 100, 15, 
15, 15, 100, 60, 1000, 50, 0, 0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 60, 20, 10, 0, 
40, 100, 5, 30, 60, 15, 10, 30, 0, 0, 20, 15, 20, 30, 10, 10, 
50, 1000, 30, 10, 20, 30, 0, 80, 0, 50, 15, 0, 30, 0, 0, 15, 
10, 60, 0, 50), q18 = c(0, 60, 0, 80, 20, 5, 0, 5, 25, 500, 250, 
70, 800, 0, 20, 100, 100, 100, 50, 50, 70, 30, 50, 0, 50, 300, 
5, 100, 50, 15, 20, 50, 30, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 90, 100, 50, 100, 
0, 10, 1000, 0, 20, 80, 5, 100, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0, 100, 0, 
0), q19 = c(0, 30, 0, 80, 0, 5, 0, 15, 25, 15, 100, 60, 800, 
50, 0, 0, 80, 0, 0, 0, 45, 20, 10, 0, 20, 500, 5, 30, 60, 15, 
50, 50, 0, 0, 50, 0, 20, 0, 20, 15, 0, 0, 0, 10, 75, 100, 10, 
80, 5, 30, 20, 0, 15, 0, 0, 20, 0, 50, 10, 0), q20 = c(100, 60, 
200, 150, 200, 30, 200, 100, 50, 1500, 100, 40, 400, 5020, 35, 
150, 80, 100, 100, 50, 70, 30, 40, 100, 50, 200, 20, 0, 50, 10, 
100, 30, 0, 60, 30, 50, 20, 30, 63, 40, 100, 100, 0, 20, 50, 
200, 50, 50, 30, 50, 30, 0, 45, 35, 30, 45, 50, 50, 30, 40), 
    q21 = c(100, 30, 200, 150, 100, 40, 100, 10, 20, 15, 100, 
    30, 400, 20, 10, 0, 60, 0, 0, 0, 10, 20, 10, 20, 15, 20, 
    5, 30, 50, 10, 10, 20, 0, 0, 0, 15, 20, 30, 15, 10, 30, 100, 
    0, 10, 15, 0, 30, 120, 10, 10, 35, 0, 2525, 35, 50, 40, 10, 
    30, 20, 15), q22 = c(100, 70, 100, 150, 100, 5, 100, 5, 25, 
    250, 100, 50, 1000, 20, 15, 70, 80, 100, 10, 20, 30, 30, 
    20, 50, 50, 200, 10, 40, 40, 15, 100, 20, 50, 60, 20, 15, 
    30, 30, 10, 30, 100, 100, 25, 20, 10, 100, 80, 50, 25, 20, 
    35, 0, 30, 20, 0, 20, 50, 50, 0, 50), q23 = c(10, 40, 100, 
    150, 100, 3, 10, 10, 20, 4, 100, 60, 700, 20, 0, 0, 60, 0, 
    0, 0, 20, 20, 10, 20, 40, 20, 5, 2, 60, 15, 10, 20, 5, 0, 
    20, 0, 30, 30, 10, 2, 1010, 0, 10, 1010, 10, 10, 5, 80, 3, 
    20, 20, 0, 25, 0, 0, 20, 10, 30, 0, 15)), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), class = "data.frame")
```

edit*: 0 is not missing data as it is values in $

when looking at it graphically it looks far from ideal

```
boxplot(as.matrix(example))
plot(density(as.matrix(example)))
```

I would like to normalize this data by a transformation and control for outliers so I have 2 questions:

**QUESTION 1**

how would you deal with outliers in this dataset. I don't want to lose data so I would like to replace them, however which method to use is unclear to me. On this matter, is there any package that would help me automate this? I also wanna look at the rationale of the method used

**QUESTION 2**

Having controlled for outliers I want to transform the variables into normality. For this I have two packages I tend to use:

```
library(rcompanion)
a<- transformTukey(as.matrix(example))
```

and

```
library(LambertW)
b<-Gaussianize(example, type = "h")
```

however I am not too sure mathematically how they work and how to asess if they are doing a good job, which is better or if there is another more practical solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you're trying to do with the data, but I would pretty much start off with the simple things and go from there. For example, what's the hist() look like and all the normal distribution (sure you can find that online somewhere better) checks. I think the one that I always go for in outliers is the simple `lm()` which will have the graphs for the outliers and where the 'cutoff' would be if you went through the graphs. Normally, the data type would also give you a little insight as to normalization methods, but in general log norm usually is a good default choice

Comment: I have one clear objective: make the data normal to perform parametrics. Another concern is that I want to automate missing data detection and imputation as I have a lot of information to process and cannot rely on a graphical implementation as you suggest. For this I have tried the rm.outlier fucntion